# X509Certificate2.FriendlyName property doesn't retrieve the certificate label on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

When i read the certificates from the Linux Store My/Root, X509Certificate2.FriendlyName property of the certificates is always an empty string.When i do the same on Windows i see that the FriendlyName property gets populated with the certificate label name.Why does the same doesn't work on Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FriendlyName is just a field in the Windows certificate store. Since Linux doesn't have the Windows certificate store, it doesn't have an analogous extra property.